# Historical stock data Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to retrieve stock prices from yahoo, or google (I've tried both) it keeps returning with this error. I don't know what it means or how to fix it. I have used this code before and it has worked well. Can you please help me with this error and a solution to fix it. Thanks.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web


start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2004,1,1)

df= web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df.head)
```

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ichart.finance.yahoo.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /table.csv?a=0&ignore=.csv&s=TSLA&b=1&e=1&d=0&g=d&f=2004&c=2000 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

Comment: This question has been asked 5-10 times on this site already.  Try the [`fix-yahoo-finance`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance) package.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this part: 
`df=web.DataReader("TSLA","yahoo",start,end)` to:   `df=web.DataReader("TSLA","google",start,end)`

The problem here is with the yahoo search engine. So hopefully this solves the issue.

Comment: This won't work either, because I guess even Google has stopped importing stock data on its main web. Kindly Check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I found:

```
# Define the instruments to download. We would like to see Apple, Microsoft and the S&P500 index.
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'SPY']

# Define which online source one should use
data_source = 'google'

# We would like all available data from 01/01/2000 until 12/31/2016.
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'

# User pandas_reader.data.DataReader to load the desired data. As simple as that.
panel_data = data.DataReader(tickers, data_source, start_date, end_date)

# Getting just the adjusted closing prices. This will return a Pandas DataFrame
# The index in this DataFrame is the major index of the panel_data.
close = panel_data.ix['Close']

# Getting all weekdays between 01/01/2000 and 12/31/2016
all_weekdays = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='B')

# How do we align the existing prices in adj_close with our new set of dates?
# All we need to do is reindex close using all_weekdays as the new index
close = close.reindex(all_weekdays)

close.head(10)
```

from http://www.learndatasci.com/python-finance-part-yahoo-finance-api-pandas-matplotlib/